# Background Fetch puzzle

Tags: ios, objective-c, fetch

I have this piece of code in my AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    ApiHandler *ah = [[ApiHandler alloc]init];
    [ah login:^(BOOL succes) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1000;
    }];

}
```

What I expect this code to do, when iOS thinks it is appropriate to do background fetch is:

1. perform the **login** method of my ApiHandler, and upon success
2. tell the Fetch mechanism everything is OK
3. raise the application badge number with 1000

Now, for some reason, the badge count is not raised, and while the **login** method is completed successfully, AND a breakpoint at

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1000;
```

actually breaks the execution, I'm worried about the successful completion of the Fetch. Since, if it's not considered successful, the app will stop trying to fetch eventually, as far as I understand.

Could any of you point me to what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance

yours truly

Comment: I thought that the `completionHandler` should be the last thing called. It indicates that you're finished doing whatever you were doing.

Comment: yeah, you should call the completionHandler as the last thing. Also, you should check on the succes parameter, and if false call the completionHandler with UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed or UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *Register Notification* before you set Badge Number.

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1000;
```

**Note:**

> You can place `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);` any
>   where. It doesn't matter.